# Accidentally moved /usr now kde is broken. Do I need to re-install?

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, kubuntu, kde

Okay, so I have a laptop with Windows 10 and KDE neon dual boot.
While trying to fix a problem (Linux root did not have enough space left) **I accidentally moved */usr* to */home***.
I tried to fix it but nothing I found online helped at all. I couldn't use sudo or su anymore and to move /usr back to root I needed those permissions of course.
And if it couldn't get worse my laptop died. So now my **Linux can't even boot-up anymore and I can't even access a terminal**.

**My questions are:**

1. If my research is correct my only option is to re-install KDE neon. Is that the case or does anyone know of some other way to still save the system?
2. If I do need to re-install I would appreciate a step by step guide - maybe someone knows a good one. I could find any.

Normally I get help from a Linux-group at my university but they are not available right now, plus their knowledge is limited too.
So please know that I mysel have only very little knowledge of all of this so please keep the answers as simple as possible.
If there is already a question like this please link it as I obviously did not find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a live session to move it back from `/home/` to `/usr/`

In `/home/` there should only be users and that tends to be 1 on de desktop so should be easy to do. Even if you moved it to `/home/$USER/` not a problem: that one holds directories like Desktop, Downloads so easy to identify.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? My linux isn't even booting-up anymore.

Comment: That's why you use a Live session (It's the "Try Ubuntu" environment in an Install USB)

Comment: @diigital who installed that machine? Not you? If someone else I would suggest to have them help. It is pretty easy to do but you need to know what you are doing and 1 slight mistake might be actually fatal.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you I will try that and report back

Comment: @Rinzwind No I was not the one installing it. I had help from someone but this person is not available right now

Comment: Finally, everything is back to normal. I did exactly what you described and it solved the problem. Thank you!